# How to call and loop through paginated API using python

Tags: python, api, loops, pagination

I am trying to call a python API to get a result set that is about 21,500 records with the PageSize limit or default at 4000 records. I also do not know the total pages and there is no "next_url" or "last_page_url" links. The only given is the total number of the results which is 21205 and than I can divide it by the PageSize limit of 4000 equaling 5.30125 pages.  
There is 2 possible ways i am thinking just i am not sure how to put it in code.

First doing a while loop to see if result set = PageSize of 4000 than loop through another page.

Second is for each loop and if total pages is 5.3 make it round to a 6 to get all records and paginate through page =+1 
Lastly I need to append all the records to ta pandas dataframe so i can export to a sql table. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
url = "https://api2.enquiresolutions.com/v3/?Id=XXXX&ListId=161585&PageSize=4000"

auth =  { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'XXX', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

params = {'PageNumber': page}  

res = requests.get(url=url,  headers=auth, params=params).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(res['result'])
total_result= df['total'][0]
total_pages = int(total_result) /4000

properties = json_normalize(df['individuals'],record_path=['properties'],meta= 
['casenumber','individualid','type'])

properties['Data'] = properties.label.str.cat(properties.id,sep='_')

properties = properties.drop(['label','id'],axis=1)

pivotprop = properties.pivot(index='individualid', columns='Data', values='value')

data = pivotprop.reset_index()  

data.to_sql('crm_Properties',con=engine, if_exists='append'
```

Answer (score 4):

are you looking for something like this ? You just loop until the result size is less than 4000 and consolidate the datas in a list

```
url = "https://api2.enquiresolutions.com/v3/?Id=XXXX&ListId=161585&PageSize=4000"

auth =  { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'XXX', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
page = 0
params = {'PageNumber': page}  

pages_remaining = True
full_res = []

while pages_remaining:
    res = requests.get(url=url,  headers=auth, params=params).json()
    full_res.append(res['result'])
    page += 4000
    params = {'PageNumber' : page}
    if not len(res['result']) == 4000:
        pages_remaining = False
```

Comment: Hello Maxime not exactly because the result set is put into a list. I need to be able to put the results into a pandas dataframe. This is what i get when i do df=pd.DataFrame(full_res)  .......                                                                                   result
0  {'total': '20238', 'individuals': [{'casenumbe...

Comment: Hello Maxime not exactly because the result set is put into a list. I need to be able to put the results into a pandas dataframe. This is what i get when i do df=pd.DataFrame(full_res) ....... result 0 {'total': '20238', 'individuals': [{'casenumbe...

Comment: Hello @TB_new I was just giving you the general method, you are free to adapt it, also as far as I know a pd.dataframe can take an iterable, so it can take a list as a parameter.